# Django Class view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

**urls.py**

```
from housepost.views import ListingPost
...
url(r'^house_post/$', ListingPost.as_view(), name='post_house'),
...
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class ListingPost(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.error(request, 'asdf', extra_tags = 'error')
        return HttpResponse('Hi')

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListingPost, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

I'm returning an HttpResponse on a get request, yet I keep getting an error:

**error message**

> The view housepost.views.ListingPost didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to post it. But it's there.

Comment: Are you implementing something else like `dispatch`?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor Yes, I am.

Comment: is the user logged in,in this case.You have placed a decorator for checking that.

Comment: @user2190496 For your next questions...You saw it's bad thing omitting relevant info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dispatch` returns a `HttpResponse` but you don't return anything when you override it. This is the method that calls `get` or `post` and returns the response on their behalf. So the following should work:

```
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(ListingPost, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dispatch method needs to actually return the result of calling the superclass method:

```
return super(ListingPost, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```