# Django form dispatch method : value error : view returned None instead of HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

**What I want to do :**

I am checking if user is from "support" group before he can view the page. If not I want to show proper message in response page to user.
I have group_required decorator applied on dispatch() method of view that checks if user is from support group or not.

**I have tried** :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29744943/2286762
but still getting the ValueError.

**my code**

**view.py**

```
class ScheduledTestView(FormView):
    '''
    Provides an admin panel interface for creating scheduled tests.
    Scheduled test will be created as active=False intially.
    '''
    serializer_class = TestShortSerializer
    template_name = 'admin/scheduled_test.html'
    form_class = ScheduledTestForm

    @method_decorator(group_required(['support']))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ScheduledTestView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**group_required function**

```
def group_required(group_names):
    """
     group_name will be the list of group name
    """
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func, assigned=available_attrs(func))
        def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
            user = request.user
            if user.is_authenticated():
                if (user.groups.filter(name__in=group_names) and user.is_staff) or user.is_superuser:
                    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                return redirect_to_login('/admin/')
        return inner
    return decorator
```

**Error**

> GET
>   Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/support/scheduled_test/
>
> Django Version:   1.8.4
>
> Exception Type:    ValueError
>
> Exception Value:
>   The view support.views.ScheduledTestView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
>
> Exception Location:    /home/kishan/.virtualenvs/kishan_pal/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 151

Comment: What does `inner` return if the user is not authenticated?

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Daniel Roseman mentioned in his comment below your question. If user is not authenticated then `inner` does not return any response whereas it should return `redirect_to_login('/admin/')` in that case.

So changing

```
def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        if (user.groups.filter(name__in=group_names) and user.is_staff) or user.is_superuser:
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return redirect_to_login('/admin/')
```

to

```
def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated():
        if (user.groups.filter(name__in=group_names) and user.is_staff) or user.is_superuser:
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return redirect_to_login('/admin/')
```

should resolve the issue. See the difference `return redirect_to_login('/admin/')` is outside the `if` block.